# SQL Server column alias has no effect

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to rename a column name in order to aid mapping data from this database into another for a data push.

What I need to do is change the name of `StdType` to `IncomeType`, although no matter what I try it simply does not change the column name in the result.

This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT
    'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) AS AAID, 
    Description, 
    Convert(Money,Amount)/100 AS Amount, 
    Note, 
    StdType FROM [Finstat_Income] AS IncomeType
INNER JOIN #Assessments A
    ON 'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) = A.AAID
```

`#Assessments` is a temporary table which does exist and works for my other queries.

`Finstat_Income` is a table and not a view. I've also tried the query with and without square brackets but there is no difference.

The resulting output is headed as:

```
AAID | Description | Amount | Note | StdType
```

Where my desired output is:

```
AAID | Description | Amount | Note | IncomeType
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are Aliasing the table, not the column. Try this -

```
SELECT
    'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) AS AAID, 
    Description, 
    Convert(Money,Amount)/100 as Amount, 
    Note, 
    StdType AS IncomeType
FROM [Finstat_Income] 
INNER JOIN #Assessments A
    ON 'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) = A.AAID
```

Comment: Of course I am, can't believe I missed that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Put your alias next to the column name.

```
SELECT
'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) AS AAID, 
Description, 
Convert(Money,Amount)/100 AS Amount, 
Note, 
StdType AS IncomeType
FROM [Finstat_Income] 
INNER JOIN #Assessments A ON 'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) = A.AAID
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this

```
SELECT
'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) AS AAID, 
Description, 
Convert(Money,Amount)/100 as Amount, 
Note, 
StdType as [IncomeType] FROM [Finstat_Income] AS IncomeType
INNER JOIN #Assessments A
ON 'AA' + CAST(ClientID AS VARCHAR) = A.AAID
```

Comment: change the column alias not same with table alias

Comment: who said that?. are you saing `select t1.Col1 as [t1] from table as t1` this wouldn't work?